# as well as any man could/might know them

Tags: modal-verbs

*"Of course," said Jamie; "of course I'm going to let you. I'm going to let you do exactly what you please and I am going to go with you and see how much assistance I can give in teaching Americanism. I’ve had some fairly stiff training to fit me to teach Americanism. There are a few things I know about the war end of the game about as well as any man **could** know them..."*

The excerpt above is from the 1920's American novel, The Keeper of the Bees.
We have here a former Army soldier answering his fiancée's question if he would allow her to go on with her job as teacher of Americanism after they get married. He expresses his approval and even his willingness to help her, seeing himself fit for the job.

Q: Would it be OK to use "might" instead of "could" above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"could" here means "be able to".

> about as well as any man could know them.

means "as well as it is possible for any man to know them."

One could also write

> about as well as any man might know them.

with a similar meaning, but I think that use of might is a bit more old-fashioned then the version with could, with is already a little out-of-date (as might be expected from the date of the text).